# How to access a public method from a wrapped Component using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am working on a React project using TypeScript. They wrapped the [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) component into another component. The wrapped component is the following:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { Props as SelectProps } from "react-select/lib/Select";

export interface SelectValue {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface SelectFieldProps<TValue> extends SelectProps<TValue> {
  label?: string;
}

type GenericSelectField<TValue> = React.StatelessComponent<
  SelectFieldProps<TValue>
>;

const SelectField: GenericSelectField<SelectValue> = ({
  label = "",
  ...rest
}) => (
    <div className="react-select-wrapper">
      {label ? <span className="input__label">{label}</span> : null}
      <Select classNamePrefix="react-select" {...rest} />
    </div>
  );

export default SelectField;
```

I would like to access the method `blur` from react-select:

> React-select exposes two public methods:
>   ...
>   blur() - blur the control programatically

But, I don't know how to expose it in my Component, so I could invoke it. Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to use `blur`?

Comment: I am gonna call blur in another Component as a result of an user action. I don't think relavant to show here, because there it is just a method call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ref` property on the `Select` component to get a reference to the instance of this component.

Then you can call the `blur` method of this instance.

```
const SelectField: GenericSelectField<SelectValue> = ({label = "",...rest}) => {
  const selectEl = React.useRef(null);      

  // this function could be a callback
  function handleBlur() {
    selectEl.current.blur();
  }

  return (
    <div className="react-select-wrapper">
      {label ? <span className="input__label">{label}</span> : null}
      <Select ref={selectEl} classNamePrefix="react-select" {...rest} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SelectField;
```

If you need to access the `blur` method outside of your `SelectField` component, you could use [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components) to reference `Select` instead of the `SelectField`.

```
const SelectField = (props, ref) => {
  const {label = "",...rest} = props;
  const selectEl = React.useRef(null);      

  return (
    <div className="react-select-wrapper">
      {label ? <span className="input__label">{label}</span> : null}
      <Select ref={ref} classNamePrefix="react-select" {...rest} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default React.forwardRef(SelectField);
```

Then you can call the `blur` method with the reference of the `SelectField` component :

```
const ref = React.createRef();
<SelectField ref={ref} label=""/>;

ref.blur();
```

Comment: I am implementing your suggestion, but the TypeScript part is something. I am trying to declare in my interface the blur method, but it is not working. Is this correct? `export interface SelectFieldProps<TValue> extends SelectProps<TValue> {
  label?: string;
  blur?: Function;
}`

Comment: don't really understant what you are trying to do. Do you need to access the `blur` method of `react-select` outside of your `SelectField` component ?

Comment: That's it. I am using SelectField into another Component. There, I'd like to call blur().  The code is pretty complicated, but I am relying on refs there too: `<PriceRangeFilter
              from={filters.priceGte}
              to={filters.priceLte}
              onChange={(field, value) => {
                selectRef.current.map(select => select.blur());
                return onPriceChange(field, value)
              }}`

Comment: I edited my answer, you will need to update the `SelectField` type

Comment: your answer is real nice and I guess it works fine with React + JS. But I am still struggling with TypeScript. TS requires the blur method to be explicitly declared into SelectField and it is not happening. I can't just invoke the function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you want to trigger **Select's** blur() inside of **SelectField**.

There are many ways for example parent-child-binding it via props.
Here is a discussion about this:

[Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: This discussion don't address TypeScript. Refs do the work, but the function must be declared inside the Component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it from outside the `SelectField` component, I would recommend using `React.forwardRef` to forward the `ref` prop to your `SelectField` component so you can assign it on your own:

```
/* ... */

type GenericSelectField<TValue> = React.StatelessComponent<
  SelectFieldProps<TValue>
>;

type SelectFieldWithRef<TValue> = React.StatelessComponent<
  SelectFieldProps<TValue>,
  React.Ref<*>
>;

const RefSelectField: SelectFieldWithRef<SelectValue> = (props, ref: any) => {

    /* ... */

    return (<Select ref={ref} {...} />);
};

const SelectField: GenericSelectField<SelectValue> = React.forwardRef(RefSelectField);

export default SelectField;
```

In the component you want to call `blur` you have to do the following:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.selectRef = React.createRef();
    }

    somehowTriggerBlur = () => this.selectRef.current.blur();

    render() {
        return (<SelectField ref={ref} {...} />);
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is with TypeScript. The SelectField must declare the blur function, so, I can invoke it outside the Component.

Comment: @Aldo I have updated my answer with possible typings.